# Adobe Flash: Getting the Alt-Ctrl behaviour back to normal

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, adobe-flash

When typing, many of the special characters I type are with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> is ], for example. Those are characters essential when writing code. But this term, at school, we're learning to program in Flash, with ActionScript.  For some reason, Flash, just like Illustrator and Photoshop [those two are somewhat understandable since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> change the tool you're using], blocks me from doing that. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> does nothing in Flash.

Those characters can be typed with <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>, the right-hand <kbd>Alt</kbd>, instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>. But that's crazy impractical. It forces me to move my left hand quite far on the right side of the keyboard, and that's inefficient.

This is pretty annoying. I could type the code in another software, but being in Flash and able to test my things with a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> is a notable speed boost as well. Is there a way to return this to normal?

PS: The problem doesn't really show itself on a Mac, where it's replaced by another, more global one: the Mac keyboard uses left <kbd>Alt</kbd> only to type those characters. (Pretty inconvenient since the key isn't even in the same place as Windows' <kbd>Alt</kbd>, but anyway.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flash overrides Firefox keyboard shortcuts -- how to turn that off?](http://superuser.com/questions/172952/flash-overrides-firefox-keyboard-shortcuts-how-to-turn-that-off)

Comment: @PaulSweatte it may not have been clear in the question but I was talking about Adobe Flash Professional, the creation and programming software, not Adobe Flash Player.